# JavaScipt: Pass HTML entities as function parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-entities

Is there any way to pass `HTML` entities as function parameters in JavaScript.

I am building a React app and I need to pass `HTML` entities from parent component to child component as a `prop` and then display character represented by that entity in the child component.

For example, please refer stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qearyj).

In `Hello` component I need to print `htmlEntity` received from App component as a `prop` and display character represented by that entity, in this case it would be symbol - ''.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in react.

```
function createMarkup(str) {
  return {__html: str};
}

function MyComponent({str}) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(str)} />;
}

const myText = 'First &middot; Second';
<MyComponent str={myText} />}
```

another way is to use Unicode characters with escape notation (e.g. \u0057) instead of HTML codes (·).

```
function MyComponent({str}) {
  return <div>{str}</div>;
}

const myText = 'First \u0057 Second';
<MyComponent str={myText} />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
 const htmlEntity = <div>&#247;</div>;
 return (
  <div>
   <Hello htmlEntity={htmlEntity}/>
  </div>
 );
}

const Hello = ({htmlEntity}) => (
 <div>{htmlEntity}</div>
)
```

Implement it like this